# Почему не отображается кастомная иконка?

Tags: flutter, dart

пытаюсь добавить кастомную иконку, однако ничего не получается, она просто не отображается на экарне. Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка и как ее исправить?

myConfig -

```
class CustomIcons {
  CustomIcons._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'MyFlutterApp';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData airline_seat_recline_normal = IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData map_marker = IconData(0xe833, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData sliders = IconData(0xf1de, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

pubsec.yamal -

```
- family: CustomIcons
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Icon-Place.ttf
```

Использую так -                  `Icon(CustomIcons.sliders)`

Comment: а можно ссылку на файл со шрифтом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сами собирали шрифт в TTF?
Я сомневаюсь, что его семейство - `MyFlutterApp`.

Насколько я понимаю, должно быть так

```
class CustomIcons {
  CustomIcons._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'Icon-Place'; // Здесь указывается семейство(название) шрифта
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData airline_seat_recline_normal = IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData map_marker = IconData(0xe833, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData sliders = IconData(0xf1de, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

Если название файла шрифта отличается от названия семейства - откройте файл в любом просмотрщике шрифтов и узнайте название семейства из него.

После чего укажите в конфиге.
(*Если не имеете возможности - приложите файл к вопросу*)

Вероятность этого высока, поскольку в свободном доступен я не нашел одноименного набора иконок или шрифта с таким названием.

---

**Исключительно в качестве примера:**
Скачал и открыл в просмотрщике FontAwesome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выделении видно название семейства шрифта